# Enable memory compression without enabling pagefile in Windows 11

Tags: windows-10, memory, compression, windows-11, pagefile

It seems that when the pagefile is disabled, memory compression does not work.

But according to the descriptions, this feature (memory compression) was exactly developed to make pagefile not needed.

Why then is it disabled if there is no pagefile, however small it is?

Can I enable memory compression without enabling pagefile?

Comment: No; What you want is not possible.  The pagefile has always been required to use the memory compression feature of Windows 10 and newer. Whereever you read the memory compression was developed so the page file wasn't needed is inaccurate.

Comment: @Ramhound it works when the pagefile is as small as possible, even 1 MB.

Comment: What works exactly? You asked if you can disable the page file (as in have no page file), and will Windows still perform memory compression, the answer to that question is a resounding "no"

Comment: Every open program (exe, dlll, or font) are page files. There are two types of pages that get paged - code pages and data pages. Only data pages go into the swap file. You are forcing Windows to keep unused data pages in memory and to swap out code pages. In addition you are reducing the memory available to file caching. In short Microsoft already optimised it by a very large number of experiments.

Comment: The file cache prevents disk access when you use start your programs or open your files. That's the point of it. You want it as big as possible. The file cache is what the available memory is being used for except for a little bit kept free so there's space to start a new program.

Comment: @user1644677 my own experience shows very well that with pagefile enabled the system is MUCH slower.